# Problem to access data from a firebase project in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the data from a project I have in Firebase for a React application but the result of my request is an object that I can't interpret.

The rules are set as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

javascript

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
  apiKey: "**************************",
  authDomain: "*******.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://********.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "*********",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "**********",
  appId: "*******************************"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.database();

var flow = db.ref('FlowRate');
var humdity = db.ref('Humidity');

console.log(flow);
console.log(humdity);
```

The console.log returns:

```
{
    orderByCalled_: false,
    path: Object { pieces_: (1) […], pieceNum_: 0 },
    queryParams_: Object { limitSet_: false, startSet_: false, startNameSet_: false, … },
    repo: Object { repoInfo_: {…}, dataUpdateCount: 0, nextWriteId_: 1, … },
    <prototype>: Object
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote constructs a reference to certain data in the database. It does not however yet read that data.

To read the data, you'll want to do something like:

```
flow.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Note that this is a quite basic interaction with the Firebase Database, so I highly recommend checking out the documentation on [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), and [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data). A few hours spent there will save you much more time going forward.

Comment: The code I was relying on is probably deprecated, I will read the documentation. Your solution worked here, thanks so much for helping Frank.